# Relationship between two points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am given the question:

$y - 2 > -3x$

$x \leq -1 -y$

In the $xy$ plane, if the point with co-ordinates $(a, b)$ lies in the solution set of the system of inequalities above, which of the following relationships between $a$ and $b$ must be true ?

1. $a<0$
2. $b>0$
3. $ab>0$
4. $ab<0$
5. $a>b$

I was able to determine that $y > -3x + 2$
and $y > -x - 1$

What should be done next ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given

$$y - 2 \gt -3x \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$x \le -1 -y \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note your second determined inequality of $y > -x - 1$ is not correct. It should be $y \le -x - 1$ instead.

Multiplying both sides of \eqref{eq2A} by $-3$ gives

$$-3x \ge 3 + 3y \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Combining with \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$y - 2 \gt 3 + 3y \implies 2y \lt -5 \implies y \lt -\frac{5}{2} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Moving the values to opposite sides (or multiplying both sides by $-1$) in \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$3x \gt -y + 2 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Next, multiplying sides of \eqref{eq4A} by $-1$ gives

$$-y \gt \frac{5}{2} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Combining this with \eqref{eq5A} gives

$$3x \gt \frac{5}{2} + 2 \implies x \gt \frac{3}{2} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Finally, \eqref{eq4A} and \eqref{eq7A} show, with $a = x$ and $b = y$, that statements $1$, $2$ and $3$ are never true, but statements $4$ and $5$ are always true.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah it was a silly mistake from my side. Thanks for pointing it out. It was a basic equation, I was seeing it from the geometry perspective and got confused. Thanks anyways :)